Question about the Hopfield Network Model in Psychology & Neuroscience was flagged as spam
I recently posted a question about the Hopfield Network Model and its potential applications in treating Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder (OCD) and depression on the Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange forum. The question is titled 'About Exploring the Hopfield Network Model in the Treatment of Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder and Depression: Current Research and Future Directions' and can be found here.
However, this question was flagged as spam and subsequently deleted by a moderator. The comment left by the moderator was: 'This is not an appropriate use of this website and could be considered spam.' Bryan Krause.
I'm confused about why this question was flagged as spam. It seems to me that it's a valid question that could contribute to a discussion in the field of neuroscience. Is there something about the way I phrased the question that led to it being flagged as spam? Or is there a misunderstanding about the purpose and guidelines of the forum?
I'm interested in understanding how the forum operates and what the community's expectations are for the type of questions that are appropriate to ask. I believe that having a clear understanding of this can help to prevent similar issues in the future and contribute to a more productive and engaging community


Actually, I didn't flag your question as spam because that could result in penalties against your use of your account and I didn't want to trigger that. I instead used a regular deletion and posted a comment to let you know the reason. Unfortunately, I did not add a link to https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/promotion as I should have so you could understand the policy that makes your question inappropriate.
Please do not post questions of the form "here's my blog post/article/etc, what do you think?" Questions must be self contained and focused. They must not rely on outside resources where someone would need to read the content of a link to understand the question, because that content may disappear from the Internet or be changed and therefore ruin the content here on StackExchange.
If you insist on linking to your own content elsewhere as necessary to read your question, it appears as self-promotion and will be removed.

My position is stronger: Please do not post questions of the form "here's my pet theory / personal ideas / random ramblings - what do you think?"  In fact, please do not post questions of the form "... what do you think?"  Questions that invite opinion or discussion, are off-topic here.  Copying the content of the blog into the body of the post won't fix this.

@ArnonWeinberg Yes, I agree with you, I should have been more clear about that: this form of question would also not be acceptable if the content were posted here in its entirety.
